# SQL - recursive CTE - Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a bill of material with a recursive CTE in SQL. However, I have problems with the matching types and I can't explain why. I have looked at several threads of people who had the same problem but the only ideas I got is to cast to the same type. That worked for the column Quantity but not for Part and Position as you can see below.

```
WITH iterate (Module, Part, Description, Quantity, Position)
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        @item, CAST(@item AS VARCHAR(100)), parts.Description, CAST(1 AS DECIMAL), CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM (ProductItems AS parts
        INNER JOIN ObjectReference AS ref
        ON parts.Item = @item)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        @item, CAST(parts.Item AS VARCHAR(100)), parts.Description, CAST(ref.Qty AS DECIMAL), CAST(ref.Pos AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM iterate
        INNER JOIN ObjectReference AS ref
        ON ref.Child = iterate.module
        INNER JOIN ProductItems AS parts
        ON ref.Parent = parts.Item
    )
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM iterate
```

I get these two error messages:

- Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Part" of recursive query "iterate".
- Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Position" of recursive query "iterate".

Do you have an explanation for that and a possible solution?

I would highly appreciate it. Thank you!

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: please provide the table defintions so we can see the datatypes

Comment: the parts.Item is varchar(50) and ref.Pos is varchar(255)